# Why word2vec create word- embeddings so fast?

Tags: python, gensim, word-embedding

Python 3.9.6

I wrote the code to create word- embeddings for my domain (medicine books). My data consists of 45,000 normal length sentences (31 519 unique words, 591 347 all words). When I create / learn a model:

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec(sentences,
                 min_count   = 5,
                 vector_size = 200, 
                 workers     = multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
                 window      = 6
                 )  
model.save(full_path)
```

,it's trained about 1- 2 seconds, and the size of the saved model is about 15MB.

How can I check the correctness of the creation my word- embeddings?

Answer (score 0):

There's not really 'correctness' for word-embeddings, just 'usefulness for desired purposes'.

Especially when you are training-up domain-specific vectors, for some specific intended task, you should try to create your own mix of evaluations.

Those might start as some ad hoc sanity checks, like: "if I look at `model.most_similar('esophageal')` (or many other probe words), do the results make sense to me?"

But it's even better if your evaluations are some repeatable quantitative scoring – such as a bunch of words that 'should' be closer-to-each-other than other words – that could be run, quickly, against a new model where you've tweaked parameters or added training data, to rank it against other models.

And best if your downstream application – info-retrieval, or classification, or recommendation, etc – itself has some robust scoring against ideal results, and you can apply that back to indicate whether one set of word-vectors is better than another for that use, and by how much.

Separately: that's not a very big training set for word2vec, but might be enough for some useful results. But that might be suspiciously fast completion. Try enabling logging at the `INFO` level, and watch the progress info to make sure it's making sense at each step. Test if using more than the default `epochs=5` has the expected effect of making training take more time. (One common mistake is to pass a mere *iterator*, that's only capable of producing the training data once, instead of a true *iterable* that be be re-iterated many time, to the model. That error allows the model the one pass it needs to discover the vocabulary but not the `epochs` additional passes it needs for real training.)